# MySQL database target machine actively refuses connection

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying, for the past few days, to get a script on one server to connect to a MySQL database on another server.  I've looked all over to see if I could find a solution and I've made little progress.  What I'm doing is reading from a local database, then using that information to write to the desired database (which has a table of the same name).  The code is as follows.

```
require_once($documentRoot."/Classes/DBHandler.php");

$db_controller1 = new DBHandler();

$query = "SELECT ...";
$temp = $db_controller1->select($query);

//Convert temporary database contents into usable result
while($rowObject=mysql_fetch_object($temp)){
    $result[]=$rowObject;
}

//Create database handler to handle target database
//Server actively refuses this connection.  Wrong IP address or user?
$db_controller2 = new mysqli("ip address:3306", "user", "password", "DB name");

if($db_controller2->connect_errno){
    $errorMessage = sprintf("'%s'", $db_controller2->connect_error);
    echo $errorMessage;
}
else{
    $db_controller2->query("DELETE ...");

    //Processing of data goes here
    foreach($result as $item){
        //Create query to insert individual records
        $start = "INSERT INTO ...";
        $end = sprintf("remainder of insertion query here");
        $start .= $end;

        //Database handler uses $start to insert record
        $db_controller2->query($start);
    }

    $db_controller2->close();
}
```

Everyone I've talked to has agreed that the IP address itself is correct.  What I find weird is that when I view the database after logging in through cPanel, the URL shows a port number of 2082 but checking database variables gives me a port number of 3306.  All of the SQL queries are correct and there's nothing wrong with the PHP code.  The errors I've been receiving differ depending on which port number I use.  For 3306:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\etc.\script.php on line 30
'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. '
```

When I use 2082, I get a different error message:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\etc.\script.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=[PID here] in C:\etc.\script.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\etc.\script.php on line 28
```

I'm completely at a loss of what to do.  Most of what I've seen seems to indicate that this is a server-related problem and I'd need to either create a new user with remote access permissions or modify an existing user to permit remote access, but for whatever reason, I can't do either of those things because there *is no option* for remote access.

Does anyone have suggestions?  Connecting to the target database is no problem for any files on its same server.

Note: The "line X" messages are incorrect since I slightly modified what I posted here for confidentiality reasons.  However, they're referring to the line where I create the new mysqli object.

Comment: I wonder if this has much to do with PHP/SQL itself. Do you use a firewall or anything of the sort to prevent making connection?

Comment: I'm not really sure so I'm looking into it.  I've been told that the best solution for a scenario like this is replication, but since we need to be able to control when this script updates the database table, we can't really use replication.

Comment: Here are instructions from within cPanel http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/

Comment: This is not a PHP issue. The error indicates that the issue is with the server. Either it has a firewall blocking connections from the network, or the MySQL daemon is not configured to answer the network.

Answer (score 0):

On the machine running the target MySQL instance....

What is in your my.cnf file?

Probably here:

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
```

Make sure that skip-networking is commented:

```
# skip-networking
```

Make sure bind-address is bound to the correct IP address:

```
bind-address 65.55.55.2
```

Lastly, check your firewall.

Comment: I'll have to ask my boss about how to get access to our my.cnf file since I think the server this specific database is hosted on isn't physically present in this building, and I don't think I have the information to connect to it with TeamViewer.  Would I need to modify the bind-address to the address of the machine trying to access it, or just to its own IP address?

Comment: Just to its own address, external address.  Can you connect to the database with a SQL tool?

Comment: What kind of tool?  I normally access it through cPanel to check up on one table to make sure another script is updating it properly.  I'm not sure that's what you're talking about though.

Comment: A SQL query tool.  So that you can confirm that it is able to be connected to.   There could be a few other security features preventing access.

Comment: May need to grant the access from the web server:
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO YOUR_USER@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

Comment: @Barmar at this point we dont know if there is a network issue.  It could be the database rejecting the connection due to access privileges.

Comment: I have access to WHM.  Do you think I might be able to fix the problem through there?  If so, what should I check?